# Button defaults to being disabled even though I enabled it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Button keeps being disabled even though a specified it to be enabled

I've tried placing the enabling code in different areas, but nothing has worked.

```
btn_Receipt.setEnabled(true);
btn_Reset.setEnabled(true);
txtA_ProofOfPurchase.setEnabled(true);

double deposit = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please specify the amount of money that you would like to withdraw (in Rands)"));

String name = "Nia Sanderson";
String action ="Deposit";

txtA_ProofOfPurchase.setText
    ("******************************* \nNedbank Online Banking  " +
      "\nCustomers Name: " + name +
      "\nAction: " + action +
      "\nDeposit Amount: R " + deposit + 
      "\n*******************************"      
    );
```

I expect the output to result in the two buttons and text area being enabled

Comment: In the first place which property you've used to disable the buttons?
Is it enabled property or disabled?

Comment: the enabled one

Comment: This might need a bit more (and less) code. Everything starting from the third line seems to be unrelated to your button. We don't see the code where you declare the button and we don't know which method the given code example is in. Please provide a bit more info about that.

Comment: You can update your question with the code of button declaration or creation which might help us to find the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to java and do not know what those mean, please can you help me understand what you mean by that. All I know is that before this method/event I had the buttons disabled

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).